# Configuring webpack to bundle ES2015 JavaScript into standard JavaScript, through babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, material-components, mdc-components

Why does [MDC Getting Started (Step 3)](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#step-3-webpack-with-es2015) say, "We need to configure webpack to bundle ES2015 JavaScript into standard JavaScript, through babel"?

Will someone from Google please clarify the circumstances under which:

- "Standard" (I imagine they mean pre ES2015) JavaScript **is** necessary
- "Standard" (I imagine they mean pre ES2015) JavaScript **is not** necessary

Comment: It depends on what browsers you want to support, if it's only modern browsers you probably don't even need babel.

Comment: What even is “standard” JavaScript other than JavaScript according to the ECMAScript 2018 spec, currently? If they mean ECMAScript 3, ECMAScript 5 or ECMAScript 5.1, they should probably clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

ES2015 is also "standard JavaScript", but it is still "quite new" and a a lot of clients still use browsers that do not suport it. Thats why you have to fallback to an older version if you want to support all clients, if you don't care of them you don't need that step.

Comment: There is still very little browser support for modules, so most clients will barf at a pure es2015 solution

Comment: @anilRedshift okay except modules